# Excel is it possible to Change or set a value of A1 by the formula in the A2

Tags: excel

Say there is nothing in `A1`, then is Is it possible to Change or set a value of A1 by the formula in the A2?

Comment: what about a formula in A1, that depends by A2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is no built-in function for that, it can certainly be achieved via VBA. You can find a solution here:

https://superuser.com/questions/602216/how-do-you-write-an-excel-formula-that-will-paste-a-specific-value-in-a-differen

Hope it helps.